# CKEDITOR : Restrict keys using blockedKeystrokes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have a problem with restricting ALT and WINDOWS keys in my CKEditor.

My Current method is like this

```
config.blockedKeystrokes =[1114203,18];
//18 ==> ALT 1114203 ==> WINDOWS
         (OR) 
config.blockedKeystrokes =[1114203,CKEDITOR.ALT];
```

But, those are not working on my end.

What should I do now?

-Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it works in my case :-
4456466 is keycode of alt.

```
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(e) {
    e.editor.on('key', function (event) {
        console.log(event.data.keyCode);
        if (event.data.keyCode == 4456466) {
            console.log("here");
            event.cancel();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block these keys I would recommend using a key listener and blocking both of them based on code. Please note that listener should be attached when editor instance is fully initialized (`instanceReady` event) and not only created.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {});
editor.on('instanceReady', function( e ) {
    e.editor.on( 'key', function ( event ) {
        var key = event.data.keyCode;
        if ( key == 4456466 || key == 91 ) {
            //console.log( "here" );
            event.cancel();
        }
    });
});
```